# How do i center an image in a jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I recently got into bootstrap and I'm having difficulties with the jumbotron element. Whenever i try to add an image to the jubotron and center it or just in general move it it is not working with normal css3. I did my research and cannot find anything on it...

I gave my picture a class and tried moving it using margins, but 
that is simply not working out. The picture is not moving regardless of what i do.

Thanks to everyone in advanced.

EDIT:

HTML:

```html
<div class="middle-container-2">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3 text-center">Go Pro. Stay on top!</h1>
    <p class="lead text-center">Premium gives you access to the Pro scrims instantly and is the only way to support the site!</p>
    <img class="mx-auto d-blok text-center unlock-icon" src="Unlock-icon.png" alt="Unlock"/>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <p class="text-center">It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
    <p class="lead">
      <a class="read-more-button btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.unlock-icon {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Please review [jumbotron image is not centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984596/jumbotron-image-is-not-centered),this might be useful for you.

Comment: Look at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9bvkchwg/), it works just fine. You can also use float, but I would recommend flexbox

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rectify the `d-blok` class with the `d-block` one on your `img` tag.
After that, you can remove the `text-center` class and add the `img-fluid` class.

```html
<img class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid unlock-icon" src="Unlock-icon.png" alt="Unlock"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `text-center` to align text-like contents and `mx-auto` to centered block-level  tages is most popular tricks using with **Bootstrap**

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/#text-alignment
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>      
    <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
  
  <p>This is some text.</p>      
  <p>This is another text.</p>      
  
  <div class="text-center"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/mediumrectangle/222222/eeeeee">
  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

add image in div and give that div some alignment like center or right

```css
.image-holder {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>      
    <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
  
  <p>This is some text.</p>      
  <p>This is another text.</p>      
  
  <div class="image-holder"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/mediumrectangle/222222/eeeeee">
  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: The question is tagged with `boostrap-4` but you recommended to create the existing `text-center` bootstrap 4 class. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4

Comment: FYI, when I answer this question OP did not add his code/html and my solution provide solution to his problem