# How I center and resize my image within the jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to noy only center my image but also resize it since its to large. I want my image to sit right above my navigation just like similar websites. How can I achieve this?

```css
.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="jumbotron">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551308719-c0e80e6becc9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" width="200px">
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">COLECTION</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you really using Bootstrap 4? The markup looks like Bootstrap 3.

Comment: [jumbotron image is not centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984596/jumbotron-image-is-not-centered)

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't a perfect solution to this because of the dimensions of the image you selected. If you stretch this image 100% width and only the height of the jumbotron, the image is going to be very distorted. Assuming you don't want the image height to stretch the entire screen, you could do something like this:

```css
.jumbotron {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551308719-c0e80e6becc9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">COLECTION</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this **CSS** to align and resize image with your `jumbotron`

```
.jumbotron img{
  width:100%;
  height: auto
}
```